# Minecraft log in help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i have changed my mc email to login and I haven't set up the security questions and I forgot the email. I know my username and password but I need the email to log in. Does anyone know how to log in with just the username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Mojang's support portal, you need to locate your transaction ID of your game. This transaction ID is an identification number located in the email your received to confirm that Mojang has received your payment for the game.

To make it short, the transaction ID is the proof that you bought the game. I think it could also be found in your PayPal transction history if you bought the game with PayPal.

Once you have found your ID, contact the Mojang support from this page: [Link!](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new)

If you want to take a look at the support page from where I took this information, you can click [here](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/329530-my-email-account-has-changed-)

Comment: Thx TheBird956!!

Comment: @tommay No problem! Dont forget to mark my answer as accepted so other users know this question has been answered and might be usefull for them.