# How do I log into minecraft with my account username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't know my email because I haven't had to use it in years. Now I'm suddenly expected to remember it. I know my account name and password but I need my email to log in, how can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft log in help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/186194/minecraft-log-in-help)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem awhile back.
 Your best bet is to contact Mojang [at their contact section](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new) and explain that you do not have access to the email that you originally signed up with (or in this case, explain that you don't know which email you used) . They will most likely ask you for proof of purchase associated with the account name.  They can then set the email for your username to one that you would like.